# Show a notification from watchOS 2 app

Tags: swift, watchkit, uilocalnotification, apple-watch, watchos-2

It is possible to show a notification from Apple watchOS 2 native app? Although watchOS 2 applications can run directly on the Apple watch device, it still hasn't reference to the `UIApplication.SharedApplication`, so I can't all the `UIApplication.presentLocalNotificationNow()` directly from the WatchKit app an it seems that also the `WKExtensionDelegate` cannot be used to show instant notifications.

Answer (score 1):

The `WKExtensionDelegate` can respond to local notifications via the `didReceiveLocalNotification(_:)` method. Your iPhone app will have to schedule the notification. If it is an even that only the watch knows about, you can send a message to the phone app using the `WCSession` set of APIs.

Comment: This two step approach (send message to the iPhone app to fire a notification on Watch) works, but I need to use my Watch app as standalone app (when my watches are out of iPhone BT range), so this solution is not applicable for me.

Comment: I have had similar difficulty getting the full desired functionality I need from WatchKit. As it currently stands, not everything can be achieved. I'm sure more be made available in Watch OS 3